# The clearInterval() function doesn't clear Interval In React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Im doing this:

```
startinterval = () => {
    this.interval = setInterval(this.intervalFunction, 10000)
}


clearInterval = () => {
    clearInterval(this.interval)
}
```

but when i call the **clearInterval** function it doesn't do anything and the interval continues

Comment: How are you calling `clearInterval()` function on a button click or||?!! show us more code

Comment: Does the `this` in both functions refer to the same object? Chances are, it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using functional components you can use:

```
function MyComponent() {
  const [intervalId, setIntervalId] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    let id = setInterval(() => {
      //Code to do
    }, 10000);
    setIntervalId(id);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
    };
  });

  return <div>UI Here</div>;
}
```

If you are using a class as component:

```
class MyComponent {
    intervalId;

  componentDidMount() {
    this.intervalId = setInterval(() => {
        //Code to do here or call another function
    }, 10000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
      clearInterval(this.intervalId);
  }
}
```

The best important to take in advance is that you need store the id for clear the timeout. If you lost the correct id the clear function won't work correctly.

Comment: omg thank you so much the thing that i was missing was the`intervalId;` in the component